# How can cond from Racket be written using only logcal operators?

Tags: racket

For my homework, I need to write a recursive function without any conditional statements, only logical operators and I don't have any idea how to write cond using only logical operators. Can someone help?

For reference I wrote this code for my function using if and cond:

```
(define (is-preferred? pref-list x y)
  (if (null? pref-list)
    #t
    (cond
      ((equal? (car pref-list) x) #t)
      ((equal? (car pref-list) y) #f)
      (else (is-preferred? (cdr pref-list) x y))
      )
    )
  )
```

And I tried to write it using only logical operators and it doesn't work for all cases:

```
(define (is-preferred? pref-list x y)
  (or (null? pref-list)
    (or (equal? (car pref-list) x)
     (and (equal? (car pref-list) y)
         (is-preferred? (cdr pref-list) x y)
     )
    )
   )
  )
```

Comment: Could you add your test cases (data -> expected result)?

Answer (score 2):

Try this - note that I placed ending parentheses on one line:

```
(define (is-preferred? pref-list x y)
  (or (null? pref-list)
      (equal? (car pref-list) x)
      (and (not (equal? (car pref-list) y))
           (is-preferred? (cdr pref-list) x y))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Think about your conditions and the result for a while.

Then you will see that the result is `#t` if and only if

- `(null? pref-list)` is `#t`, *or*
- `(equal? (car pref-list) x)` is `#t`, *or*
- `(not (equal? (car pref-list) y))` is `#t` *and* `(is-preferred? (cdr pref-list) x y)` is `#t`.

Then translate into Racket.